# Matplotlib has blank space below table

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have made a table in matplotlib and I am using `plt.savefig` to save the table as a png, the problem is there is a lot of blank space underneath the table.
[image]
I need the bottom of the image to end closer to the table rather than have those 2 inches of blank space underneath.

Here is all the relevant code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis("off")


colLabels = ["BLANK", "BLANK", "BLANK", "BLANK", "BLANK", "BLANK", "BLANK"]
colColors = ["#4472c4"] * len(colLabels)
colWidths = [0.22, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15]

cellText = [["0", '0', '0', '0', '0', "0", "0"]] * 9
cellColors = [["w"]*len(colLabels) for i in cellText]

table = ax.table(cellText=cellText, cellColours=cellColors, cellLoc="right", colWidths=colWidths, colLabels=colLabels, colColours=colColors, colLoc="center", rowLoc="left", loc="upper center")

for cell in table.get_children():
    cell.set_edgecolor(None)


for col in range(len(colLabels)):
    table[(0, col)].set_text_props(color="#FFFFFF", fontweight="bold")

plt.title("TITLE")
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: `savefig`  output should match the displayed figure. Does it? If so, compact the window size or fit the contents better (e.g. `fig.tight_layout()`). If not, then you may have a matplotlib bug.

Comment: Maybe `plt.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight')` works for you?

Comment: I tryed bbox_inches="tight" and it didnt work, also yes the savefig output does match the displayed figure from plt.show(), the displayed figure also has the extra space on the bottom.  @blarg how do i change the window size?

Comment: If `tight_layout()` doesn't work (and it may not, it only works for a limited set of plot items), an easy brute-force thing you can do is play with the `figsize=(width_inches,height_inches)` option in the `plt.subplots` call to get something that looks nice by eye. Follow the link under the `**fig_kw` option in the [official docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html#matplotlib-pyplot-subplots) for details.

Comment: Using figsize=(inches, inches) worked!!  thanks for the help, I'm curious as to if there is a better solution though....